# What is wrong with this complex circuit analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

I tried mesh analysis of this simple circuit but it is wrong, i can't figure out why though.
I simply applied KVL using the two mesh currents.[image: mesh]

EDIT:
the phasor Ig is known so i make the obtained linear system in a system with Vx1 and I2 as unknowns.
Plugging in the data from the problem:

R1 = 2;

C1 = 0.333;

L1 = 2;

Ig1 = −2;

C2 = 1;

R2 = 0.5;

ω =1;

I solve the system. The correct solution is Vx = -3-6j though.

[image]

Comment: Is the device on the right a voltage source or a current source?

Comment: Also, what result did you get? Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The device on the right is a current source, i think that my analysis is wrong because solving the linear system lead me to results different from the solutions

Comment: Please update your question to show your work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the attention, give me a few minutes to write it down

Comment: Question updated with my work, i double-checked the math, i really don't know where i am wrong..

Comment: According to your matrix equation \$V_{x1}=12+j0\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitutions of \$I_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are incorrect.

\begin{cases}
  -V_x+I_2(j \omega L_1)=-I_1(R_2+j \omega L_1)
\\
\\
  0 +  I_2(R_1+\frac{1}{j \omega C_1}+\frac{1}{j \omega C_2}+j \omega L_1)=-I_1(j \omega L_1)
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
  -V_x+2jI_2=\color{red}{-(-2)}(\color{red}{0.5}+2j)=1+4j
\\
\\
  0 +  (2-2j)I_2=\color{red}{-(-2)}I_1(2j)=4j
\end{cases}

The last part of your calculation is correct, but used incorrect values.
For completeness, I'll continue with the correct values.
Compared to your solution \$I_2\$ actually changes sign, so:
$$  I_2=-1+j$$
Substiting this into
$$-V_x+2jI_2=1+4j$$
yields
$$V_x=2j(-1+j)-1-4j=-3-6j$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's write the current source as follows:

$$\text{I}_{\space\text{s}}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}\cos\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\tag1$$

We can write that into the complex notation as follows:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{s}}=\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\tag2$$

Where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$.

Now, the input impedance can be calculated using:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\text{R}_2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\text{||}\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)=\text{R}_2+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{L}\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\right)}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}}=$$
$$\text{R}_2+\frac{\text{L}\left(\frac{1}{\text{C}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_2}\right)+\omega\text{L}\text{R}_1\text{j}}{\text{R}_1+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega}\left(\frac{1}{\text{C}_1}-\frac{1}{\text{C}_2}\right)\right)\text{j}}\tag3$$

In order to find the input voltage we need to find:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{s}}=\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{\text{L}\left(\frac{1}{\text{C}_1}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_2}\right)+\omega\text{L}\text{R}_1\text{j}}{\text{R}_1+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega}\left(\frac{1}{\text{C}_1}-\frac{1}{\text{C}_2}\right)\right)\text{j}}\right)\tag4$$

The time function of the input voltage is given by:

$$\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|\cos\left(\omega t+\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)\right)\tag5$$

---

Using \$\text{R}_1=2\space\Omega\$, \$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{2}\space\Omega\$, \$\text{L}=2\space\text{H}\$, \$\text{C}_1=\frac{1}{3}\space\text{F}\$, \$\text{C}_2=1\space\text{F}\$ and \$\omega=1\space\text{rad/sec}\$ we find for the input impedance:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{3}{2}+3\text{j}\tag6$$

So, we will get:

- $$\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|=\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{s}}\right|=\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{s}}\right|=\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}\sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3+3^2}=\frac{3\sqrt{5}\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}}{2}\tag7$$
- $$\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{s}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)+\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{s}}\right)=$$
  $$\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)+\arg\left(\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)+\arg\left(\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}\right)+\arg\left(\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\right)=$$
  $$\arg\left(\frac{3}{2}+3\text{j}\right)+0+\varphi=\varphi+\arctan\left(2\right)\tag8$$

So:

$$\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\frac{3\sqrt{5}\hat{\text{i}}_{\space\text{s}}}{2}\cos\left(\omega t+\varphi+\arctan\left(2\right)\right)\tag9$$

Comment: Man i love your analysis, and how you simplified the circuit. Still, i can't see where i did wrong in my analysis, because clearly you are obtaining the right result and i'm not..